# Do I have an LCD panel issue?

Tags: colors, lcd, calibration, contrast

I have a brand new replacement Asus Monitor. I'm either having difficulty calibrating it, the panel itself has an issue or my eyes have an issue. No matter how much I adjust the R G B levels, contrast and brightness settings white backgrounds and gray colors appear bright and blotchy straining my eyes and causing double vision. A blink might cause another object to appear in the white, or a flashing yellow spot for example. Static photo images such as desktop backgrounds don't seem to be an issue, it is mainly the whites and grays in the Chrome browser that is hurting my eyes.

I owned the same monitor for 12 months+ prior to getting this new one just a week ago and never had such difficulty. Could the panel have an anti glare coating issue or a factory calibration issue? Or should I consider having my eyes checked?

Comment: This would be hard as there are too many variables you can check - Eyes checked.. how about asking 2nd opinion? Get someone else to look at it and see if they are suffering from the same condition? Get a comparison monitor side by side and see if you are still getting the same effect out of it? Have a different PC you can connect to it?

Comment: When I received the new monitor I had it and both the old one with me before I returned it. Had I known this was going to be an issue I would have done a side by side comparison. It didn't occur to me since I have not had an issue with the monitor like this before. Do the symptoms described provide any clues as to what the problem could be?